# PostgreSQL. Вставка записи по условию

Tags: postgresql

Допустим есть простая таблица:

```
id | some_fk | value
--------------------
1  | 1       | 3
```

Вставляю в нее данные таким образом:

```
insert into table (some_fk, value) values (1, 3) returning id
```

Как можно запретить средствами СУБД вставку записи, если для такого `some_fk` такое значение уже есть?

Тоесть в данном случае, например `values (1, 4)` вставить можно, а `values (1, 3)` нельзя, так как запись с такими значениями уже есть.

Структуру БД менять не могу. Только читать и писать данные в таблицу.

Comment: структуру таблицы изменить можно? посмотрите на ограничение уникальности https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/unique.php

Comment: Да, это было бы хорошим решением, но под структурой БД я имел ввиду структуру таблиц тоже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Правильно

Добавить уникальный `constraint` или построить уникальный индекс. Это крайне родственные два понятия, с лёгкими различиями синтаксиса и возможностей создания.

### Грабли и велосипеды

Если правильное решение по какой-то странной причине невозможно, то можно ценой заметных накладных расходов прыгать на костылях вокруг.

```
insert into tablename (some_fk, value) 
  select 1, 4 
  where not exists (select 1 from tablename where some_fk = 1 and value = 4)
returning id
```

Подход простой, но из-за видимости транзакций или `race condition` может давать неверный результат в итоге. Поэтому необходимо в транзакции сперва захватить подходящую блокировку на таблицу. Минимально подходящей будет [`SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE` lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html), которая заставит ждать все параллельные транзакции желающие модифицировать данные этой таблицы:

```
begin;
lock table tablename in SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE mode;
insert into tablename (some_fk, value) 
  select 1, 4 
  where not exists (select 1 from tablename where some_fk = 1 and value = 4)
returning id;
commit;
```

Намеренно блокировать любые изменения в таблице на всё время транзакции вместо выполнения проверки уникальности только конфликтующих между собой транзакций, понятное дело, может ухудшить производительность системы весьма значительно. Поэтому не стоит использовать этот способ без сильной на то причины.

### Велосипед №2

Если вам заметно повезло, и вы можете со своей стороны контролировать *все* операции записи в эту таблицу - то вы можете воспользоваться [`advisory locks`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS). Идея та же самая, но вместо большого `lock table` запрашиваете пользовательскую блокировку с каким-то ключом.

```
begin;
select pg_advisory_xact_lock(
   /* выберите ключ из одного bigint 
      или двух int для этой задачи, 
      имеет смысл в каком-то виде использовать 
      желаемое значение some_fk */
);
insert into tablename (some_fk, value) 
  select 1, 4 
  where not exists (select 1 from tablename where some_fk = 1 and value = 4)
returning id;
commit;
```

Но повторюсь - это будет работать только если вы можете гарантировать, что в таблицу пишете значения только вы сами.

---

Если ни уникальное ограничение ни lock table ни гарантию что вся запись осуществляется только вами вы получить не можете - у вас будут появляться дубли либо происходить ложные срабатывания проверки существования строки. Просто запрос с `not exists` часть, возможно большую часть, прикроет, но не будет являться гарантом.

Comment: Спасибо за шикарный ответ, жалко нельзя несколько раз плюсануть.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вот этот `select ... where not exists ...` в первых двух велосипедах надо еще обернуть в `values(...)`?

Comment: Прошу прощения. Вижу что не правильно.

Comment: Это частный случай `insert ... select ...` синтаксиса, то есть `insert ... returning` - отдельно, а внутри может быть совершенно любой select, результат которого и будет использован в качестве значений для `insert`